# Not able to get the title of Page using geb when it has multiple div elements and no ID

Tags: spock, geb

Below is my html, from where I am trying to get the text of header. I tried multiple ways to select it but not succeeded in it. Could you please help me to get the element so that I can get the text.

```
<div class="esuite-right">
    <div class="angular-css ng-panel ng-panel-boxed">
        <div class="ng-panel-hdr">
            <h2 class="ng-binding">
                Case-10006336-2015
                <span class="sch-tek "> | </span>
                Case details
            </h2>
        </div>
        <!-- ngIf: zaak.vertrouwelijk -->
        <div>
    </div>
```

Title of the frame is "Case-10006336-2015" and tried to locate the element by using below various ways however not able to succeed in it.

1. `labelSelectedCase { $("div", class: contains("angular-css ng-panel ng-panel-boxed")).$("div", class: contains("ng-panel-hdr")).$("h2",class: contains("ng-binding") ) }`
2. `labelSelectedCase { $("div.angular-css ng-panel ng-panel-boxed div.ng-panel-hdr").find("h2", class: contains("ng-binding")) }`

and several others but not able to locate this element.
Could you please help me to get this element so that I can get the text and assert it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Either of these should work -

1. `labelSelectedCase { $("h2.ng-binding")}`
2. `labelSelectedCase { $("span.sch-tek").parent()}`

I'm not sure Content defined like you have in 1) is even valid so that could explain why $(x).$(y).$(z) doesn't work, and I'm pretty sure 2) goes astray at the second and third classes of the first div, maybe you have to chain the classes if you want to select on multiple classes like this -

```
labelSelectedCase { $("div.angular-css.ng-panel.ng-panel-boxed div.ng-panel-hdr").find("h2", class: contains("ng-binding")) }
```

Good luck,

Deon.